# Создание многомерного массив в цикле foreach, смещение массива в цикле

Tags: php, парсер, simple-html-dom

В результате парсинга, сохраняю данные в многомерный массив.

```
    foreach ($html->find('div.pc-product-loop__col') as $page) {
    $title = $page->find('div.product-loop-title');
    $data['title'] = reset($title)->plaintext;

    $description = $page->find('div.product-cut__extra-info');
    $data['description'] = reset($description)->plaintext;
    
        foreach ($page->find('div.attributes-list__row') as $featureItem) {
            $featureName = $featureItem->find('div.attributes-list__name');
            $feature[] = reset($featureName)->plaintext;

            $featureValue = $featureItem->find('div.attributes-list__value');
            $feature[] = reset($featureValue)->plaintext;

            $data['feature'] = $feature;
        }
         $product[] = $data;
}
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($product);
```

В результате чего получаю многомерный массив, но проблема в том что на втором уровне массива с каждым циклом значения дублируются.

```
 `array (size=8)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'title' => string 'Надувная лодка Aqua-Storm Mini &#8211; Зеленый' (length=66)
      'description' => string 'Гребная лодка ПВХ 
      'feature' => 
        array (size=10)
          0 => string 'Тип судна' (length=21)
          1 => string 'гребная лодка ПВХ ' (length=43)
          2 => string 'Количество мест' (length=33)
          3 => string 'одноместная лодка' (length=44)
          4 => string 'Грузоподъемность лодки, кг   ' (length=52)
          5 => string '60' (length=13)
          6 => string 'Вес лодки, кг ' (length=26)
          7 => string '3' (length=12)
          8 => string 'Диаметр баллона лодки, см  ' (length=48)
          9 => string '21' (length=13)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'title' => string 'Надувная лодка Kolibri K-190X' (length=42)
      'description' => string 'Гребная лодка ПВХ 
      'feature' => 
        array (size=20)
          0 => string 'Тип судна' (length=21)
          1 => string 'гребная лодка ПВХ' (length=43)
          2 => string 'Количество мест' (length=33)
          3 => string 'одноместная лодка' (length=44)
          4 => string 'Грузоподъемность лодки, кг' (length=52)
          5 => string '60' (length=13)
          6 => string 'Вес лодки, кг' (length=26)
          7 => string '3' (length=12)
          8 => string 'Диаметр баллона лодки, см' (length=48)
          9 => string '21' (length=13)
          10 => string 'Тип судна' (length=21)
          11 => string 'гребная лодка ПВХ' (length=43)
          12 => string 'Количество мест' (length=33)
          13 => string 'одноместная лодка' (length=44)
          14 => string 'Грузоподъемность лодки, кг' (length=52)
          15 => string '100' (length=14)
          16 => string 'Вес лодки, кг' (length=26)
          17 => string '6.6' (length=14)
          18 => string 'Диаметр баллона лодки, см' (length=48)
          19 => string '28' (length=13)
  2 => 
    array (size=5)
      'title' => string 'Надувная лодка Kolibri K-210Х' (length=43)
      'description' => string 'Гребная лодка ПВХ
      'feature' => 
        array (size=30)
          0 => string 'Тип судна' (length=21)
          1 => string 'гребная лодка ПВХ         ' (length=43)
          2 => string 'Количество мест' (length=33)
          3 => string 'одноместная лодка' (length=44)
          4 => string 'Грузоподъемность лодки, кг' (length=52)
          5 => string '60' (length=13)
          6 => string 'Вес лодки, кг' (length=26)
          7 => string '3' (length=12)
          8 => string 'Диаметр баллона лодки, см' (length=48)
          9 => string '21' (length=13)
          10 => string 'Тип судна' (length=21)
          11 => string 'гребная лодка ПВХ' (length=43)
          12 => string 'Количество мест' (length=33)
          13 => string 'одноместная лодка' (length=44)
          14 => string 'Грузоподъемность лодки, кг' (length=52)
          15 => string '100' (length=14)
          16 => string 'Вес лодки, кг' (length=26)
          17 => string '6.6' (length=14)
          18 => string 'Диаметр баллона лодки, см' (length=48)
          19 => string '28' (length=13)
          20 => string 'Тип судна' (length=21)
          21 => string 'гребная лодка ПВХ' (length=43)
          22 => string 'Количество мест' (length=33)
          23 => string 'одноместная лодка' (length=44)
          24 => string 'Грузоподъемность лодки, кг' (length=52)
          25 => string '110' (length=14)
          26 => string 'Вес лодки, кг' (length=26)
          27 => string '7' (length=12)
          28 => string 'Диаметр баллона лодки, см' (length=48)
          29 => string '28' (length=13)`
```

И так далее по нарастающей. Не могу разобраться, гугл не помог :( Как исправить и что посоветуете???

Comment: массив то обнулять надо на каждой  итерации, а не постоянно добавлять в него. зы: чтобы избавиьтся от `reset` для певого элемента используете 0-индекс у find:  `->find("xxx", 0)`

Comment: бесполезную переменную`$feature[] = ...` замените на `$data['feature'][] = ...`

Comment: @InDevX на вкус и цвет, как говорится. вполне себе нормальная переменная.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хоть и голосовал за закрытие вопроса, оставлю ответ с корректировками синтаксиса относительно `reset`.

Ошибка ваша, очевидно, в том, что вы постоянно добавляете данные в массив, не обнуляя его в цикле по `$page`.

```
foreach ($html->find('div.pc-product-loop__col') as $page) {
     $title = $page->find('div.product-loop-title', 0);
     $description = $page->find('div.product-cut__extra-info', 0);

     $features = [];
     foreach ($page->find('div.attributes-list__row') as $item) {
         $name  = $item->find('div.attributes-list__name', 0);
         $value = $item->find('div.attributes-list__value', 0);

         $features[] = [
              'name'  => $name->plaintext,
              'value' => $value->plaintext,
            ];
     }

     $products[] = [
           'title' => $title->plaintext,
           'description' => $description->plaintext,
           'features' => $features
        ];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли. Заработало!

Comment: @Avyazovoi тогда галку у ответа ткните